# Multitenant setup with master account

Tags: php, database, laravel, multitenancy

I would like to make a SaaS which would be a multitenant system. Development is done in Laravel, which is less important. What I would like to know is how would you handle having a master admin account (for me) with which I could observe number of tenants, subscriptions and their types, permissions and so on?

Currently I have a setup where each new tenant gets his own subdomain (so tenant t1 would be at `t1.example.com`).

Now what bothers me with routes and system integrity is that I have a table/model `Users` where a single user can belong to a single tenant, whereas a tenant have many users. In this setup it feels somewhat unnatural to have my admin account belong to no tenant as I believe that can bring more problems down the road.

Having a dummy tenant also crossed my mind, but I'm not sure this is a right path to go as well.

I was also thinking of having a split system which would be responsible for non-tenant specific stuff, so that on the one hand I could observe tenants and system-wise actions, while the other system would be tenant oriented so that it has all the necessary DB relations. I suppose in this setup I would have to have 2 separate `User` models so that one is not dependant on tenant. This feels like a lot of duplication though.

What are your experiences?

Answer (score 2):

> What I would like to know is how would you handle having a master admin account (for me) with which I could observe number of tenants, subscriptions and their types, permissions and so on?

You can have a separate domain admin.example.com. Also have a list of reserved subdomains which won't be allowed for tenants.

> Now what bothers me with routes and system integrity is that I have a table/model Users where a single user can belong to a single tenant, whereas a tenant has many users. In this setup it feels somewhat unnatural to have my admin account belong to no tenant as I believe that can bring more problems down the road.

Your admin login would be separate than Users. Make a separate table say: admin_users. You need to design composite primary key for your Users table. When (id, tenant_id) would be your primary key. In order for the admin users, to login to tenant website - t1.example.com, insert all records from admin_users to Users table with respective tenant_id.

```
table: admin_users // This would work mainly for admin.example.com
id, name
121, Admin 
123, Norgul

table: users // This would work for tenant's users as well as you as an admin can "login as tenant" into tenant system for debugging or setup.
id, tenant_id, admin_user_id
1, 1,  121 // admin user
2, 1, 123 // admin user
3, 1, NULL // tenant's user

table:sub_domains
id, sub_domain, tenant_id
1, t1, 1
```

This way there would be a complete separation of your admin_users and tenant users. At some point, you would need to create 1 tenant's admin user who has permissions to create other users under his tenant_id.

**Routes**

Routes would be same for all subdomains, but depending on tenant_id, you would load that tenant's data. Whatever tenant specific tables your create, you would need to have (id,tenant_id) as a composite primary key.

Based on the URL, you would detect tenant_id from sub_domains table.

**Scalable**

In future, when the traffic and transactions increase,  you could easily move the data for a particular tenant to a different database server. In your sub_domains table you would do the mapping of tenant and database.

**Non-tenant specific things**

There would be some tables like type tables, countries table, tenant_status, etc. which are not client-specific. You won't add tenant_id field in such tables. We call such tables as master tables.

**Permissions**
Say your urls are like: t1.example.com/manage_users/add_user. Where manage_user is the module and add_user as action. You can have a permission middleware or just a permission layer, which would check the permissions table for the current user and current module. If permissioned, show the page else show error message.

**Experience**

This kind of multi-tenancy architecture is most successful. I am using a similar architecture and used it earlier too. We started with single database and two schemas: admin, tenants. Then we moved tenants to different databases. As tenants increased, we created more tenant databases.
Refer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns

Comment: Of your three recent answers, this is the strongest.  It provides a reasonable amount of detail and is backed with an external reference.